# How to change the owner of a file when download it to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, force-download

```
    $file_name_with_full_path = './chitty/insurance/lic/'.$filename;
    header('Content-type: application/xls');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header('Cache-Control: public');

    if(file_exists('./chitty/insurance/lic/'.$filename))
        unlink('./chitty/insurance/lic/'.$filename);

    $xx=fopen("./chitty/insurance/lic/".$filename,"w");
    chmod("./chitty/insurance/lic/".$filename,0755);    
    chown($file_name_with_full_path, "devuser");        // change owner
    fwrite($xx,$excltable);
    fclose($xx);
```

I use chown() function, but it didn't work.Please help me to solve this

Comment: You *download from* and *upload to* a server, and I am unsure which of those two you really want to do?

Comment: [_"Only the superuser may change the owner of a file"_](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php#refsect1-function.chown-description)

Comment: I generate a file and upload it to server and download it to system